# A healthy gluten- and lactose-free diets for a teenager

Tags: diet, adolescents-teenagers

Can you provide me some examples of healthy gluten and lactose-free diet for a teenager?

Comment: Do you need to avoid gluten, because you have being diagnosed with celiac disease and avoid lactose because you are lactose intolerant?

Comment: My doctor told me to go to the lab for analysis regarding celiac disease (I'm waiting for the results, but I can't tell for sure if I have it or not) and about lactose, I don't feel so good when I'm drinking milk in general. Thanks for the question.

Comment: I had embarrassing digestive problems throughout the day until I exchanged currants for one tsp sucrose on my morning porridge. Very strange. I don’t know if there was something wrong with those currants, or if it was I that had a digestive issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No exact diets here, but just some reasoning why to eat or avoid something.

---

In a **gluten-free diet,** you need to avoid wheat and its varieties, rye, barley, triticale, malt, beer, brewer's yeast, breaded meats and commercial foods with added gluten. Here's [a detailed list of foods to avoid.](https://celiac.org/live-gluten-free/glutenfreediet/sources-of-gluten/)

What you can eat:

- Cereals: rice, corn, oats, buckwheat and others that are not on the avoid list
- Vegetables, legumes, fruits and nuts
- Meat and fish, non-breaded (some packaged products may contain gluten)
- Eggs
- Dairy

---

If you are lactose intolerant, your diet usually does not need to be 100% "lactose-free" but just **"low-lactose,"** with avoiding milk, ice cream and yogurts; hard cheeses and butter should be OK ([NIDDK.nih.gov](https://www.niddk.nih.gov/health-information/digestive-diseases/lactose-intolerance/eating-diet-nutrition)). Here's an extensive [list of foods to avoid,](https://www.drugs.com/cg/lactose-free-diet.html) but this is only for someone with severe lactose intolerance.

---

Currently, many health experts recommend to **limit:**

- Foods with added sugars: most carbonated drinks, ice-tea, energy drinks (but also fruit juices), sweets and desserts ([PubMed](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5133084/)), becuse they may stimulate food craving and thus unhealthy weight gain
- Salt intake ([Heart.org](https://sodiumbreakup.heart.org/how_much_sodium_should_i_eat)), because excessive sodium can contribute to high blood pressure and artery damage
- Red meat and processed meat, such as in fast food ([PubMed](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28446499)), which are possibly associated with some chronic diseases
- Foods with trans fats, which have "partially-hydrogenated oil" on the label, for example, certain cakes, biscuits, crackers, French-fries and frozen foods ([Cleveland Clinic](https://health.clevelandclinic.org/avoid-these-10-foods-full-of-trans-fats/)), which can raise blood cholesterol levels

They also recommend to **include enough fiber** from foods, such as whole-grain cereals, fruits, vegetables and legumes, because it can help maintain intestinal health ([PubMed](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3705355/)).

---

**For the end:**

- Listen to your gut (literally).
- Eat what you find out is good for you, for your study, work and sleep.
- Maintain a health body weight.
- Someone with bowel problems can get a lot of insight if get checked for common conditions, such as celiac disease, lactose intolerance, fructose malabsorption and food allergies.

Comment: (I didn't downvote) but you really shouldn't answer personal medical questions....

Comment: I edited the question and it's not asking for a personal advice now. I know that malabsorption conditions, such as celiac disease and lactose intolerance, often coexist, so there could be a lot of people interested in this. Also, my final advice is to have some tests.

Comment: (I also didn't downvote) but you said *"If you are lactose intolerant, your diet usually does not need to be 100% lactose-free but just low-lactose"* without references.  Can you provide any references to cover this?

Comment: Yes, [here's one](https://www.niddk.nih.gov/health-information/digestive-diseases/lactose-intolerance/eating-diet-nutrition): "People with lactose intolerance can handle different amounts of lactose. Research suggests that many people could have 12 grams of lactose—the amount in about 1 cup of milk—without symptoms or with only mild symptoms."